# how to convert exponential string to normal string in c#

Tags: c#

I am reading a column **number** from csv where the number is **123456791234567** however due to format it gets converted to 
 **number="1.23457E+14"** in the csv file.

is there any way where we can change it to original string using c# ?
 I am trying with below code :

```
decimal number = Decimal.Parse(number,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```

but the number i am getting is 123457000000000M and the actual number is **123456791234567**

any idea on this?

Comment: If you've got `1.23457E+14`,you've already lost information,there's no way to get it back. Focus con the csv generation so it does save the full number

Comment: Not every digit sequence is a number or should be stored in a number type (f.i. PostalCode, Barcode, etc.)

Comment: This is an excel problem, not a c# problem.  To solve in excel make sure the cell format is not set to General.   Make it text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, excel is converting **123456791234567** to **1.23457E+14**. In that case, you just need to format the excel cell (or potentially the column) containing the value to string, before you set the value.

If the C# program opens the csv to find the value to be **1.23457E+14**, then there is no way for you to convert it back to **123456791234567**, since the precision is already lost - unless of course the same value exists (or can be recreated) in other cells (columns)